# Calculator script php

Tags: php, calculator

I am trying to build my first script the only thing i am hung up on is i am trying to multiply something by 1.7.
So when the value is entered i want to multiply that by 1.7 and then the result will be emailed.
Can any one help.

I am building an online furniture inventory list for customers to fill out and then all the results + the cubic meters will be emailed to me. So there is a lot of script for me to write i have figured out the rest, i think. below is part of the script i have only go up to the queen bed and that is what i want multiplied by 1.7 
Thanks in Advance :-)

```
/* Data Variables */

$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$uplift = $_POST['uplift'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$post = $_POST['post'];
$delivery = $_POST['delivery'];
$city2 = $_POST['city2'];
$post2 = $_POST['post2'];
$ground = $_POST['ground'];
$second = $_POST['second'];
$second2 = $_POST['second2'];
$ground2 = $_POST['ground2'];
$queen = $_POST['queen'];





$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $name <br>  
Email: $email <br>
Phone; $phone <br>
<br>
Uplift; $uplift <br>
City; $city <br>
Post Code; $post <br>
<br>
Delivery Address; $delivery <br>  
City; $city2 <br>
Post; $post2 <br>  
<br>
Uplift; <br>
Ground Floor; $ground <br>
Second Floor; $second <br>
<br>
Delivery; <br>
Ground Floor; $ground2 <br>
Second Floor; $second2 <br>
Queen Bed; $queen <br>
```

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific, I do think. But `$queen *= 1.7;` is, basically, what you need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
//$queen is POST value
$queen = $_POST['queen'];

//$queenMulti is value of $queen x 1.7, $queen will be still the post value.
$queenMulti = $queen * 1.7;
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep both answers so i know how many queen beds they enter?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, but I didn't get a notice about your comment See my update. Also you can accept my answer if this resolve your question :)

Comment: I just worked out how to accept your answer :-). as you can tell im very fresh to all this. Cheers